# user model set_password() method does not work as expected django

Tags: django, passwords, change-password

I am trying to write some code to change the password of the user which is logged in django website. The following is my code. It actually changes the password in the database, but when I try to login with the same user and the new password it doesn't log in.

```
    passw = request.POST['password']
    print(passw)
    uid = request.user.id
    u = User.objects.get(id=uid)
    u.set_password(passw)
    u.save()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you do that query on User. `request.user` is *already* the User object. You just query it again from the database for no reason.

Comment: I know there is redundancy there but i tried to call set_password() from request.user and it was not working, this way it changes the password in the db, but the hash is not the same as the hash generated by login apparently